# Symfony redirect to specific page with security annotation

Tags: symfony, security, redirect, annotations

I have a controller action which should only be able to be accessed if the user has the right role to do so.
It's already working and denying access when trying to access in the application, but when manually manipulating the path in the search bar of my web browser, it still can be accessed. Therefore I added the @Security annotation to that action, but instead of the **Access denied** message, I'd like to reroute/redirect to another page. How can i do this?

```
/**
    * @Security("has_role('ROLE_DOCUMENT_EDIT')")
    * @Route("/document/edit/{id}", name="documentBundle_edit", requirements={"id" = "\d+"}, defaults={"id" = 0})
    */
    public function editAction(Request $request, $id) {
...
```

that's the action with the security annotation and I was thinking about adding a **redirect** after it to this page:

```
      /**
    * @Route("/document/view/{id}", name="documentBundle_view_document", requirements={"id" = "\d+"}, defaults={"id" = 0})
    */
    public function viewAction(Request $request, $id) {
...
```

Comment: You could use 'access_control'(security.yml)  instead of add annotations for each function in the controller, you will have more control and you could redirect all denied  requests to another page (Login page for example) http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/security/access_control.html

Comment: I've read about doing it that way. But I have different Bundles in my project and I don't want all access_denied events to be redirected to the same page but to specific pages within the bundles.. any idea on that?@rescobar

Answer (score 0):

An example is available in Symfony. Do not forget to define the service.

https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/security/access_denied_handler.html

Comment: thanks for the link! :) I've read through the documentation, but I yet couldn't figure out how to write the code within the access denied handler. As I said, it's not for the whole project but only for one specific Bundle within it, so I'd like to get a specific redirection to the view-page for the document..

Answer (score 0):

You must respect this tree and you can personalise your Access denied exception view in your `error.403.html.twig` page. (Production mode only)

[image]

Comment: thank you @isom, I just don't want to specify the access-denied page for my whole project but only redirect within a specific bundle for the edit/view actions, so I don't think, editing my error.403 template would help me solving my problem.. any other ideas?

Comment: you can try this in your action **if($this->container->get('security.context')->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')){
  //Execute some php code } else { $this->render('yourTemplate.html.twig') }**

Answer (score 0):

SensioFrameworkExtraBundle has the possibility to add a statusCodeOption, as described [here](http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/security.html).

```
/**
* @Security("is_granted('ROLE_DOCUMENT_EDIT')", statusCode=901)
*/
public function editAction(Request $request, $id)
{
}
```

So you could probably add custom Error pages for your proprietary status codes. Haven't tested it though, just an idea.